# Using a graphql value in a variable issues?

Tags: javascript

I created the following (using supertest) and placed in a function (removed imports etc for brevity)

```
module.export = {
addThing: async function(title, done) {
    const someGraphQL = `mutation {.....}`
    
    let the_id = ""

    request
    .post("/graphql") 
    .send({
        query: someGraphQL
    })
    .set("Accept", "application/json")
    .expect(200)
    .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) return done(err);
        the_id = Prmise.resolve(res.body.data.id);
        console.log(res.body.data.id)
    })
    console.log(the_id)
    return the_id
  }
}
```

When I call this I can see the console.log with the "res.body.data.id", but not the one in the variable.

I thought this may have been async type behaviour, but as I always see that console log for the res.body.data.id (but not for the variable (no matter where I put the variable) I am confused?

Comment: This IS an async issue. The fist log works because it is composed into the promise. You need to make your function async and return the promise

Comment: But - how? With that style of function any use of async throws an error?

Comment: What does "that style" mean? You need to post your updated code and the error. We can not possibly guess how you might be using it

Comment: actually wrong code is uploaded - my apologies - will update with the correct one

Comment: Code updated.  As I am using <function name>: function(parameters) - i've never used async with that style of function definition.

Comment: What is the error you get when you add `async` and fix the return type?

Comment: Code updated.  The issue is that as the call is out to a graphql, I will get a timeout (as the call will take more than 5 seconds) - not sure if async and the call back are incompatble?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244044/discussion-between-sinanspd-and-joseph).